# Python standard library unaffected by pyc rewrite fight

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading [PEP 3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#id26) but was confused by this paragraph:

> Linux distributions such as Ubuntu [4] and Debian [5] provide more than one Python version
>   at the same time to their users. For example, Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala users can install
>   Python 2.5, 2.6, and 3.1, with Python 2.6 being the default.
>
> This causes a conflict for third party Python source files installed by the system,
>   because you cannot compile a single Python source file for more than one Python version at a time.
>   When Python finds a pyc file with a non-matching magic number, it falls back to the slower process of 
>   recompiling the source. Thus if your system installed a /usr/share/python/foo.py, two different versions of Python
>   would fight over the pyc file and rewrite it each time the source is compiled. (The standard library is 
>   unaffected by this, since multiple versions of the stdlib are installed on such distributions..)

Why is the standard library unaffected by this 'fight' between different Python versions over the pyc file?  How is it unaffected?  Does it mean it's not recompiled?  Why does having multiple versions of the stdlib installed solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each version of Python has an entire copy of the standard library, installed in a version-specific directory. So when you import a standard library, it finds the one that's already compiled correctly for that version (it has a matching magic number), so it doesn't need to recompile it.

So when you write something like `import re`, version 2.6 imports `re.py` from the 2.6 library, version 3.1 imports `re.py` from the 3.1 library, etc.

Comment: So when it says the standard library is unaffected it means the modules in the standard library don't have to get recompiled?  I don't follow why don't they?  Does Python know not to try to compile modules in a different Python version stdlib?

Comment: It gets the module from the same version.

Comment: So basically, if I ran python 2.6 and imported some source file like `/usr/share/bar/foo.py`, the pyc would be compiled for 2.6, then if I did the same thing but with like Python 2.7 or something, then the pyc file would be different which is a problem because you have to recompile `/usr/share/bar/foo.py` if you wanted to use the pyc in Python 2.6.  And the stdlib modules are unaffected by this because each Python version looks for stdlib modules in their own version-specific directory.  That's the gist of it right?

Comment: No, not when you use a full pathname. We're talking about the standard library, so you just do `import re`.

Comment: Just to clarify, which part of my previous comment is incorrect?